# Inserting UTF-8 characters into database via BPEL process

Tags: oracle, unicode, encoding, adapter, bpel

We have a BPEL process that is taking characters (e.g. Chinese) and attempts to insert them into an NVARCHAR column. The XML payload looks correct throughout the various stages (and we see the encoding is UTF-8) but when it comes to the actual INSERT we are seeing incorrect characters. Our theory is that the DB Adapter could be the problem but we do not know for sure.

Is there a way to examine the version and config of the DB Adapter, to see if it can handle UTF-8 and Unicode? We have successfully inserted Chinese and Hewbrew characters into the database using TOAD, Java servlets, etc. so the database itself is configured. It is Oracle version 9.2.0.8.0.

It may be that the fault is elsewhere than the DB Adapter so we are trying to eliminate things. Would it be worth trying to look at the HTTP header to check the encoding here?

Thanks

Comment: What is the character set and national character set of the database?  I think the national character set could be UTF-8 back in the 9.2 days though it was discouraged.  Normally, the national character set of a database would be UTF-16.  Can you clarify what you mean by "seeing incorrect characters"?  How are you seeing the characters?  Are you issuing a straight SELECT?  Are you inspecting the output of the DUMP function?  Something else?

Comment: The string we tried to insert was: ’’’English, but the apostrophe symbol is not displaying correctly (in TOAD) so it appears as ¿¿¿English whether done with a SELECT or just viewing the data in the datagrid. The NLS_CHARACTERSET is WE8ISO8859P1 and the NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET is AL16UTF16. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got to the bottom of this in the end. In a WSDL file (as part of the database connection details) we specified the defaultNChar=true property as an attribute and this was passed on to the database driver.

Comment: Congrats on the fix.  When you are able, be sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others can learn from your solution.  Cheers~